# How start an activity with fragment from another activity - Android

Tags: android, fragment

I have an Activity1 with a button.

When this button is clicked, I want to call Activity2:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/frag_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout >
```

and inside this "frag_container" I want to add a Fragment1:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <ImageView 
      android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:scaleType="fitCenter"
      android:layout_height="250px"
      android:layout_width="250px"/>

   <TextView
      android:text="Frame Demo"
      android:textSize="30px"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:gravity="center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

I can start Activity2 successfully doing this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

But I don't know how start this Activity2 with the Fragment1.

I tried adding this in OnCreate of Activity2:

```
Fragment myFrag = new Fragment1 ();
FragmentTransaction ft  = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.frag_container, myFrag);
ft.commit();
```

but Always crash when I call this Activity.

I'm new on Android, can somebody tell me how can I do this?

Comment: Can you give the Stack trace?, From what class Activity2 class is extended?

Comment: Acitivity2 extends from AppCompatActivity; and I guess, the importante part of StackTrace is:

java.lang.ClassCastException: myProject.Activity2@204b078b must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener

Answer (score 0):

Do you see a interface  inside your Fragment called `OnFragmentInteractionListener`. That is the root cause of this problem. There is nothing wrong about it but it is better for you to understand what is going on there.

In the Fragment you also should have overridden the `onAttach` method

```
@Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        this.activity = activity;

    }
```

we also do some thing like following,

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        this.activity = activity;

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
        }
}
```

To make sure that the interface is implemented (I think you have the above like code in your code.) if there is no communication with the Activity from the Fragment, comment out the `onAttach` method.

In this case you have to implement the `OnFragmentInteractionListener` on Activity2. Then it should work. We use this interface for the Fragment to communicate with the Activity. And this is how we do it.

If you attach the activity by overriding the `onAttach` in Fragment, that means you must implement the interface (But it does not matter unless you call those interface methods to call back the Activity from the Fragment)

Please have a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) to learn more about Communication between Fragments and Activities.

Answer (score -1):

Get the parent activity using get activity then do as usual.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),  Activity2.class);
                getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```